# Apache cxf and large SOAP requests

Tags: cxf

I might have a large request (SOAP) coming to an application server wildfly 20 and I was wondering how to process that request without keeping all of that request parsed in memory.

My problem is that the request itself, after the **DocLiteralnInterceptor** interceptor is invoked by CXF, becomes a full object in memory. How to avoid that? Would it be safe for me to remove this interceptor without breaking the cxf intended functionality related to SOAP request?

Default CXF in interceptors

> 1. AttachmentInInterceptor
> 2. StaxInInterceptor
> 3. ReadHeadersInterceptor
> 4. SoapActionInInterceptor
> 5. MustUnderstandInterceptor
> 6. SOAPHandlerInterceptor
> 7. LogicalHandlerInInterceptor
> 8. CheckFaultInterceptor
> 9. URIMappingInterceptor
> 10. DocLiteralnInterceptor
> 11. SoapHeaderInterceptor
> 12. WrapperClassInInterceptor
> 13. SwAInInterceptor
> 14. HolderInInterceptor
> 15. ServiceInvokerInInterceptor

My first thought would be to remove all interceptors starting from 10 to 15 included and write an interceptor that which would parse a given request in pieces (stax), but I don't know how would I process parsed chunk and how would I write a processed piece to the output stream at a same time, do I need to use threads? Do I need to remove output Interceptors (would that break cxf)?

But then again, interceptors are only for preprocessing or postprocessing the request and business logic should be invoked in the web service method, but in this case I would need to bypass web service method and from inInterceptor go straight to outInterceptor, am I right?

My second thought would be to add interceptor before **DocLiteralnInterceptor** parse a pieces of request  (let's say 1000 **subObject** elements) and wrap it in root (**object**) element and multiple times call from the interceptor chain starting **DocLiteralnInterceptor**, would this solution be possible? If so, how could I do that? In this case I would not need to bypass webservice method. But not sure if this solution is possible in general

my request object example would be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object>
   <subObject>
      <id>12</id>
      <item>
         <id>15</id>
         <name>block</name>
         ...<- other fields
      </item>
   </subObject>
   ...<- subObject element repeated 500k (500, 000) times
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can use cxf efficiently with large requests without mtom.

You could try processing the request with a Provider interface

```
public class MyService implements Provider<StAXSource> {
}
```

but if your response is also big than I doubt that provider interface would help you, as
it seems that you would need to return StAXSource which, if your request is big, consume a lot of memory.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-provider.htm#WSGET656

copy-paste from the link above

```
package examples.webservices.jaxws;
 
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
 
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.ws.Provider;
import javax.xml.ws.ServiceMode;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
 
 
/**
 * A simple Provider-based web service implementation.
 *
 * @author Copyright (c) 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. 
 * All Rights Reserved.
 */
// The @ServiceMode annotation specifies whether the Provider instance 
// receives entire messages or message payloads.
@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)

// Standard JWS annotation that configures the Provider-based web service.
@WebServiceProvider(portName = "SimpleClientPort",
    serviceName = "SimpleClientService",
    targetNamespace = "http://jaxws.webservices.examples/",
    wsdlLocation = "SimpleClientService.wsdl")
public class SimpleClientProviderImpl implements Provider<Source> {
 
  //Invokes an operation according to the contents of the request message.
  public Source invoke(Source source) {
    try {
      DOMResult dom = new DOMResult();
      Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
      trans.transform(source, dom);
      Node node = dom.getNode();
      // Get the operation name node.
      Node root = node.getFirstChild();
      // Get the parameter node.
      Node first = root.getFirstChild();
      String input = first.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
      // Get the operation name.
      String op = root.getLocalName();
      if ("invokeNoTransaction".equals(op)) {
        return sendSource(input);
      } else {
        return sendSource2(input);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in provider endpoint", e);
    }
  }
 
  private Source sendSource(String input) {
    String body =
        "<ns:invokeNoTransactionResponse
             xmlns:ns=\"http://jaxws.webservices.examples/\"><return>"
            + "constructed:" + input
            + "</return></ns:invokeNoTransactionResponse>";
    Source source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes()));
    return source;
  }
 
  private Source sendSource2(String input) {
    String body =
        "<ns:invokeTransactionResponse 
            xmlns:ns=\"http://jaxws.webservices.examples/\"><return>"
            + "constructed:" + input
            + "</return></ns:invokeTransactionResponse>";
    Source source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes()));
    return source;
  }
 
}
```

as you can see xml response strings are kept in memory.

You could also try using a Dispatch interface, i.e

(copied from the same link)

```
package jaxws.dispatch.client;
 
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;
 
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import javax.xml.ws.Dispatch;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;
 
public class WebTest extends TestCase {
   private static String in_str = "wiseking";
   private static String request = 
      "<ns1:sayHello xmlns:ns1=\"http://example.org\"><arg0>"+in_str+"</arg0></ns1:sayHello>";
 
   private static final QName portQName = new QName("http://example.org", "SimplePort");
   private Service service = null;

   protected void setUp() throws Exception {
 
      String url_str = System.getProperty("wsdl");
      URL url = new URL(url_str);
      QName serviceName = new QName("http://example.org", "SimpleImplService");
      service = Service.create(serviceName);
      service.addPort(portQName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, url_str);
      System.out.println("Setup complete.");
 
   }
 
   public void testSayHelloSource() throws Exception {
      setUp();
      Dispatch<Source> sourceDispatch = 
         service.createDispatch(portQName, Source.class, Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);
      System.out.println("\nInvoking xml request: " + request);
      Source result = sourceDispatch.invoke(new StreamSource(new StringReader(request)));
      String xmlResult = sourceToXMLString(result);
      System.out.println("Received xml response: " + xmlResult);
      assertTrue(xmlResult.indexOf("HELLO:"+in_str)>=0);
   }
 
   private String sourceToXMLString(Source result) {
      String xmlResult = null;
      try {
         TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
         transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
         transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
         OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult();
         streamResult.setOutputStream(out);
         transformer.transform(result, streamResult);
         xmlResult = streamResult.getOutputStream().toString();
      } catch (TransformerException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return xmlResult;
   }
 
}
```

On the other
hand you could write your own servlet implementation which accepts large requests and process it piece by piece and returns something as output.

But in general I doubt that one could process large requests with cxf without mtom or something similar